# Ansible manipulate variable with gsub

Tags: ansible

I have an argument that is being passed in the form of `foobar-a`

ansible-playbook test.yml -e "argument=foobar-a"

```
- name: whatever
  hosts: whatever
  tasks:
    - name: echo
      shell: echo {{ argument }}
      #should return foobar-b
```

I need to manipulate that information to be in the form of `foobar-b` What is the Ansible way of doing this?

In Chef I would just use ruby gsub to do this

```
argument.gsub!('-a', '-b')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `regex_replace` filter, like in the playbook below.

```
- name: whatever
  hosts: whatever
  tasks:
    - name: echo
      shell: echo {{ argument | regex_replace('-a','-b') }}
```

See [filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html) documentation

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

I'm not particularly fond of Ansible's documentation compared to Chef.